# ERC721 with payable function

Tags: solidity, erc721

I writed a code [enter link description here](https://github.com/SenkaKyiv/NFT_payable_tansf/blob/main/ERC721_payable_transfer) with payable function transfer.
but, after Deploy  in the "etherscan" showed me that is is not erc721, it is ERC20. can help me? where is wrong?

Comment: Please link the deployed address on Etherscan a provide repro steps to get to the same error message that you got.

Comment: errors do not appear / only after the deployment on Rinteby is written "Overview [ERC-20]"

Comment: Ok. Please share the link to the contract on a blockchain explorer with the "Overview [ERC-20]" message. My wild guess is that it's a feature of the site unrelated to the contract code, but there might be other issues related.

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x1A7C0129E5137e8113F55da028a3cd8D9d59155c?a=0x3006dfc796a1882df8642c9b3281efb5af68982d

Answer (score 0):

Testnets might not work exactly as mainnets.
They have different behaviours, that is normal.
Anyway, the methods of your smart contract are visible and can then be called.